# ACTION_SCREEN_ON broadcast in not working all the time

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have an activity that starts a service. This service (Service-A) registers a broadcastreceiver with an intentfilter "ACTION_SCREEN_ON". When this broadcastreceiver runs it starts another service (Service-B) which updates my widgets periodically until screen is off.

This is how i register my broadcast receiver & how i implement my boradcast receiver

```
//Service that register my boradcastreceiver
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    IntentFilter filterScreen = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filterScreen.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    filterScreen.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);
    filterScreen.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);

    mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filterScreen);

    return START_STICKY;
}


//My broadcastreceiver
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF))
    {
    }

    else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON))
    {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, MinuteUpdateService.class);
        context.startService(service);
    }
    else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED))
    {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, MinuteUpdateService.class);
        service.putExtra("oneTimeRun", true);
        context.startService(service);
    }
    else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED))
    {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, MinuteUpdateService.class);
        service.putExtra("oneTimeRun", true);
        context.startService(service);
    }
}
```

This flow usually works well. However sometimes my boradcastreceiver does not run as expected. It does not receive ACTION_SCREEN_ON broadcast. Usually this happens after long sleeps.

I suppose that Service-A killed/stopped by system and my broadcast is unregistered.

Is there any method that make this service/broadcast persistent? or is there another way which is more suitable for my intent?